# How to convert a binary stream into its hex representation (or UTF8)

Tags: javascript, node.js, binary, data-conversion

I've written a node-js TCP server that receives binary data (bytes) from the client. For instance the client can send data as 23 53 7f ff ff fc ... As you can see, the data consists of pritable ascii characters and non-printable as ones as well (This is not a String). For printable characters the code works fine. For instance, for 23 and 53 the script receives 23(#) and 53 (S) the problem is with bytes such as C2, when I receive EFBFBD on node js end. Is this a problem with encoding, but I am not sure.

I am using Packet Sender 6.0, an open source tool to test the functionality

I tried to use typed buffer, downloaded utf component for node js, tried different encodings.

```
manager.forwardMessage = function(listenerName, message, callback) {
//    var convertedMessage = utf8.encode(message);
//    var convertedMessage = new Buffer(message).toString('hex'); // This line prints EFBFBD for C2.
```

Next I am going to try and write some socket client in Java and send packets. Any other ideas? Any help on what I am missing is really helpful. Have spent a few days on this :).

Thanks,

Comment: Where exactly does `utf8.encode` come from? I assume that it is an instance of `Textencoder`? Just as a side node: You could skip that part and use `Buffer` directly.

Comment: You say `message` is not a string, yet `encode` expects a string as input. And you say the user data represents ascii (7 bit), yet you try to encode them as 8 bit utf-8. I am not an expert on this! But maybe that could be a source for errors? Because 7 bit can only represent values up to 128 while 8 bit go up to 256.

Comment: Marvin, Thanks a lot for your suggestions. I downloaded utf8 (npm utf8). Will try to use the buffer directly. I was going through some links describing typed bufferes, but didnt have any luck. Any links you can suggest any links?

Also User data is actually an array of  bytes (8 bits). it can have MSB set to 1 as well. Since encode expects a string, it wont be useful. I was actually expecting to receive a byte stream on node js end, but since it was all garbage looking characters, I started using methods like encode, to make some sense out of it.

Comment: You can use `Buffer.from(data)` and then `Buffer.toString("utf8" | "ascii" | etc)`. In fact Node's Buffer is only a layer on top of `UInt8Array`. And there is the `Textencoder` and `Textdecoder` in Node's `util`package (should also be available in the browser). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder

Comment: Thanks again Marvin. Cannot use Buffer.from as node js is an older version. tried
```
var convertedMessage = new Buffer(message);
log(convertedMessage.toString('<encoding (ascii, utf8, binary, hex etc.)>))
```
I want to see the hex code that I am sending from packet sender, but thats not happening. For instance if I send 0xC2 from packet sender, the node js code shows EF BF BD on node js. Is this raw binary to utf8 conversion? I am also trying iconv-lite.  iconv.decode(message, 'latin1') shows an extended ascrii character (that too I think is wrong), but I need the value. Any suggestion?

Comment: Could be that `Buffer` misinterpretates the input. But you can tell it what encoding to expect: https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings

Comment: Thanks Marvin for your help. Really appreciate it. I finally ended up upgrading node js, and it worked finally :)